# Loading resource outside unsigned applet

Tags: java, ftp, applet

I was writing an Java Applet that require to list out the ZIP file in server directory and let user to choose which ZIP file to be load.

The way I read the file:

1. Create a `java.io.File` object to hold that ZIP file
2. Use `java.util.zip.ZipFile` to read the data inside

---

My first approach to solve this problem is to make a folder in the same directory of the applet jar file in the server, then place those ZIP files there.

The placement is similar to the a.gif of the [diagram](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/figures/deployment/applet/applet-pkg.gif).

At first I tried to read the entire directory and got an error.

- java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission\Data read)

In the web I found that applet does not have this capability, so I've tried to read a specific file only, but somehow, there is still an error.

- java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission\Data\pack1.zip read)

I've try to google the problem and seems there is some problem with `java.io.File` class reading file on server. So I go for a different approach.

---

The second way I've tried is to start a FTP service allow that applet to get those ZIP files.

I use Apache Commons Net for handling FTP.

The applet was able to connect to FTP server but when `FTPClient.listFile()` was being called the log show an error.

- java.security.AccessControlException: access denied
  (java.util.PropertyPermission org.apache.commons.net.ftp.systemType
  read)

---

I understand that there is quite a lot of restriction for Sandboxed Applet, but from [Oracle's document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html) it seems that the Sandboxed Applet should be able to retrieve resources from the server it originated from, so I'm quite puzzled about how can I read that folder of ZIP file from my unsigned applet. Also, it would be nice if you guys have any suggestion on a better way to solve this problem.

FYI, the server is running Windows Server 2003 and I use JDK 6 to develop the applet.

Comment: What do you mean by "that directory"? Local directory or server directory?

Comment: sorry, I should specify it's the directory of the server which the applet originated from

Comment: The applet runs in the browser so it has no access to local in the server, so you can just read them with `FileInputStream`. Get the files through an HTTP connection to the server (the FTP does not work because it uses a different port, it is *a different server* in the same machine).

Comment: Thx, for your first suggestion, I'll try that out.
But while I was programming another Java applet in the past, I was able to connect and transmit data with a Java application on the server through a different port, so I was wondering in what situation the applet don't have access to server.